# How to Sum Numbers after Piped Values

Tags: sql, split, sum, substring

I have a column in SQL, which contains values separated by pipes. After each value, there is a number that I would like to aggregate, but I'm not understanding the best way to do it.

The columns looks like this:

```
{Carrots:1}|{Bananas:2}|{Watermelon:1}
```

I'm doing something like:

```
SELECT 
    NOME, PRICE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN VEGETABLE LIKE '%Carrots%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Carrots,
    SUM(CASE WHEN VEGETABLE LIKE '%Banana%'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Banana,
    SUM(CASE WHEN VEGETABLE LIKE '%Watermelon%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Watermelon
FROM 
    Market
GROUP BY 
    NOME, PRICE
```

But this way it only adds on value a time,

The output for column1 would be: `1 Carrot , 1 Banana, 1 Watermelon;`

But I would like to add for example 2 (when after the `:`, it's a number 2).

So would it be like: `1 Carrot, 2 Banana, 1 Watermelon.`

Comment: The proper action here is to fix the flawed database design. A column in a relational database should never hold more than one discrete value. Sure, you try to find work-arounds but in the end you would be much better off if you correct the design.

Comment: jpw, yeah I know, but we cannot change the DB... :(

Answer (score 0):

This will work, and although I do agree with the response by jpw, I've had the "pleasure" of working with data like this being sent by a client that wouldn't change their format.

```
SELECT
Name, Price,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [Vegetable] LIKE '%Carrots%' THEN SUBSTRING([Vegetable],CHARINDEX('Carrots:',[Vegetable])+8,1) ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR) + ' Carrot , ' +
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [Vegetable] LIKE '%Banana%'  THEN SUBSTRING([Vegetable],CHARINDEX('Bananas:',[Vegetable])+8,1) ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR) + ' Banana , ' +
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN [Vegetable] LIKE '%Watermellon%' THEN SUBSTRING([Vegetable],CHARINDEX('Watermellon:',[Vegetable])+12,1) ELSE 0 END) AS VARCHAR) + ' Watermellon' as Column1 
FROM Market
GROUP BY name, price
```

Output

```
1 Carrot , 2 Banana , 1 Watermellon
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code which can server your purpose.  You can convert this code into 2 functions.  One converting the string to a numeric string and then another one adding each number

```
Declare @String varchar(4000) = '{Carrots:1}|{Bananas:2}|{Watermellon:1}';            
Declare @NumOnly varchar(100) = '%[^0-9]%';
Declare @Sum int = 0;
Declare @Cnt int = 1;

--Convert String to a numeric String
WHILE PatIndex(@NumOnly, @String) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@NumOnly, @String), 1, '');
END   
SELECT @String;

--add up each character (digit) in the numeric string
WHILE @Cnt <= LEN(@String)
BEGIN
    SET @Sum = @Sum + CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@String,@Cnt,1));
    SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1;
END     
SELECT @Sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SUBSTRING()` function to achieve this, though you would be far better off changing your model as suggested in the comments.  That's not always possible, though, so if you have to work with this format you can use the following:

```
SELECT 
    NOME, 
    PRICE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN VEGETABLE  LIKE '%Carrots%' THEN SUBSTRING(VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX(':', VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Carrots', VEGETABLE ))+1, 1) ELSE 0 END) as Carrots,
    SUM(CASE WHEN VEGETABLE  LIKE '%Banana%'  THEN SUBSTRING(VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX(':', VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Banana', VEGETABLE ))+1, 1) ELSE 0 END) as Banana,
    SUM(CASE WHEN VEGETABLE  LIKE '%Watermelon%' THEN SUBSTRING(VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX(':', VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Watermelon', VEGETABLE ))+1, 1) ELSE 0 END) as Watermelon
FROM 
    Market
GROUP BY 
    NOME, PRICE
```

EDIT: as a perfect argument for why this kind of model is a bad idea, my solution above fails to take into account multi-digit numbers.  I've come up with a solution (below), which compensates for that, but am leaving the original code up as a case study in why string manipulation is no fun.

```
DECLARE @VEGETABLE VARCHAR(100) = '{Carrots:1000}|{Bananas:20}|{Watermelon:1}'

SELECT 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @VEGETABLE  LIKE '%Carrots%' 
        THEN SUBSTRING(
            @VEGETABLE , 
            CHARINDEX(':', @VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Carrots', @VEGETABLE ))+1, 
            CHARINDEX('}', @VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Carrots', @VEGETABLE )) - (CHARINDEX(':', @VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Carrots', @VEGETABLE ))+1)) 
        ELSE 0 END) as Carrots,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @VEGETABLE  LIKE '%Banana%' 
        THEN SUBSTRING(
            @VEGETABLE , 
            CHARINDEX(':', @VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Banana', @VEGETABLE ))+1, 
            CHARINDEX('}', @VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Banana', @VEGETABLE )) - (CHARINDEX(':', @VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Banana', @VEGETABLE ))+1)) 
        ELSE 0 END) as Bananas,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN @VEGETABLE  LIKE '%Watermelon%' 
        THEN SUBSTRING(
            @VEGETABLE , 
            CHARINDEX(':', @VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Watermelon', @VEGETABLE ))+1, 
            CHARINDEX('}', @VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Watermelon', @VEGETABLE )) - (CHARINDEX(':', @VEGETABLE , CHARINDEX('Watermelon', @VEGETABLE ))+1)) 
        ELSE 0 END) as Carrots
```

Comment: It works great, big thanks! (luckily , there will be no multi-digit ;) )

Comment: I'm happy to help! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.